# How do I unencrypt emails from a pst file without a digital certificate?

Tags: encryption

I saved a pst file on a CD.  It contains a lot of email that was sent to me using a digital signature.

I am now in a lawsuit and need to print out those emails but no longer have access to my digital certificate or the other persons digital certificate.

Is there a way to unencrypt those emails without.

I think they were using Outlook 2007.

Thanks

Comment: `.pst` files are just Outlook format _personal storage_ files that hold your emails, and on their own have nothing to do with any kind of encryption. You will need to install Outlook and import your `.pst` file in it. Follow instructions here: [How to manage `.pst` files in Microsoft Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287070). Chances are, digital certificates were only used to confirm identity of the sender (signed) and no encryption was used, so you should be able to read them from the Outlook folders where they were marked to be stored in.

Comment: The certificate doesn't matter, since it's just the public key. What matters is that you have to find your private key to decrypt, if you used encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the messages are encrypted?   PST needs to be on a hard drive, and can't be read from a read only medium like a CD.  Copy it to your hard drive and open the PST from Outlook.

Was the PST encrypted, or just an individual message?  Did they use PGP or SMIME?  Often these messages are send "signed" and not encrypted.

If you lost your personal SMIME or PGP key then there is no way to recover the data unless the person who created your key did something called Key Archival where they also have a copy of the key.